# How to find mouseclick first and if not clicked, then go for mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseclick-event, onmouseclick

How to find `mouseclick` first and if not clicked, then go for `mouseover` ?

I had implemented two types of functionalities in two mouse events. One in `mouseover` and the other in `mouseclick`.

If I clicked, i need to trigger `mouseclick` event first, instead of `mouseover` event. I know that by default, `mouseover` is triggered first. But how to achieve this type of scenario.

Code:

```
$('.example').mouseover(function (event) {
    // ...
    //mouse over logic
    // ...
});

$('.example').mouseclick(function (event) {
    // ...
    //mouse click logic
    // ...
});
```

Note:

> Alos, I tried with timer, set control flags but in each try, only
>   `mouseover` is triggerd first. Both `mouseover`
>   and `mouseclick` has different functionalities. If both are same, then
>   we can put in common. But, here the case is different. I had also
>   searched over the net for this. But nothing helped till now. Thanks.

Comment: I nned to show info only on `mouseover`

Comment: how do you know if the user intends to click or to mouseover?

Comment: yes, that is the problem. Trying how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: you need to buy a neural interface for each of your users and based on the result of that   neural interface you decide if you do mouseclick first or mouse over :)))

Comment: I guess we can achieve by going on `mouseover` wait for some seconds, then if the user clicked within that seconds, then go for `mouseclick` else `mouseover`. But we need to properly code this because I tried but not able to achieve the required solution.

Comment: you can do that on mouseenter

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? May it's a problem with your algorithm?
Can you explain here, what do you want to do?

Comment: Any one can have the solution for this ?. Thanks.

Comment: @madalinivascu, With `mouseenter` also, I tried but not working properly.

Comment: @JohnStephen see the solution

Comment: @JohnStephen i've updated the solution see it..

Comment: You have to be over it to click so the mouseover is going to fire first.... So what do you want it to do? You want mouseover to wait X number of seconds before firing to wait for a click?

Comment: @ASK, No. Its not working. After I clicked, the `mouseenter` functionality is not working. `isNotClicked` is in false state. So, its not entering inside `mouseenter` logic

Comment: i've updated my answer and it works in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozgvfjzs/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
var timer;
$(".example").on("mouseenter",function(e){
        timer=setTimeout(function(){ 
            // onmouseenter if not clicked
            $(".example").css({background:"red"});    // for testing
        }, 2000);
});

$('.example').click(function (event) {
    clearTimeout(timer);   // Don't call the onmouseenter
    $(".example").css({background:"blue"});    // for testing
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ozgvfjzs/

Comment: Above code triggers the `mouseenter` event and executes, after the `mouseclick` event executes when mouse has been clicked.

Comment: @JohnStephen just add another variable to check if `click` was executed, and then add an `if` statement inside the `timeout` function

Comment: @ASK, No. Its not working. After I clicked, the `mouseenter` functionality is not working. `isNotClicked` is in false state. So, its not entering inside `mouseenter` logic

Answer (score 0):

What about defining the mouseover event in the click event?

Example:

```
$('.example').mouseclick(function (event) {
    // ...
    //mouse click logic
    // ...
    $(body).bind('onmouseover', '.example'){
         // mouseover logic
    }
 });
```

I didn't tested tough...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- Trigger the event manually:

  ```
  $(this).trigger('mousehover');
  ```

  Place that inside the click handler.
- Store the handler in a variable and run it manually inside the click handler.

Should be easy enough to implement it yourself